# React JS Accessing JSON as State

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm completely brand new to React JS and am trying to create an application that will grab JSON data from a pokemon API, which I will then use to display on screen. Right now, I have it set up so that the user has to input the name of the pokemon they are looking for, i.e. pikachu, and when the search button is pressed, the application will make the API call to return the JSON. I've been searching for the past few days, and cannot seem to find anything to work with the way I currently have my code set up. How do I bind the JSON output to a component that I would then be able to display to the user?

Here's the js code (App.js)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  

   handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Text field value is: ' + this.state.value);

  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+this.state.value+'/')  
    .then(  
   function(response) {  
     if (response.status !== 200) {  
    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +  
      response.status);  
    return;  
     }
     // Examine the text in the response  
     response.json().then(function(data) {  
    console.log(data.name +" "+ data.id);  

     });  
   } 
    )  
    .catch(function(err) {  
   console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);  
    });

    }


  render() {
   
   
   
    return (
    
    
    
      <div className="App">
      
      
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        
        <input type="text"
        placeholder="enter name of pokemon here"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search the Pokedex</button>
        
        
      </div>
      
      
      
    );
    
    
    
  }
}
export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tag above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQsfQ.jpg [image]

Comment: Keep the data you get as `json` in your component state

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Could you give me an example of the syntax?

Comment: Try the below code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      data: {} //filled by fetch data from API
    };
  }
  

   handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Text field value is: ' + this.state.value);
     var _this = this;
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+this.state.value+'/')  
    .then(  
   function(response) {  
     if (response.status !== 200) {  
    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +  
      response.status);  
    return;  
     }
     // Examine the text in the response  
     response.json().then(function(data) {  
    console.log(data.name +" "+ data.id);
                _this.setState({data: data});

     });  
   } 
    )  
    .catch(function(err) {  
   console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);  
            _this.setState({data: {}});
    });

    }


  render() {
   
   var data = this.state.data;
   
    return (
    
    
    
      <div className="App">
      
      
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        
        <input type="text"
        placeholder="enter name of pokemon here"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Search the Pokedex</button>
      <h3>{data.id}</h3>       
      <h3>{data.name}</h3>
        
      </div>
      
      
      
    );
   
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tag above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to `bind(this)` to your class functions while calling them

Comment: I used the code you provided, but it seems like it's still not showing up on the "handleSubmit" function. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Use the updated code now, yes I binded the `this` to your class functions

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I'm getting a "this is undefined" type error, and unfortunately, the output still does not appear. I'm adding a screenshot to my question so you can see.

Comment: Now try the updated one. I updated `this` with another local variable

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll continue to throughly read through this to gain a better understanding of react. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Yes it's now printing on the screen and everything.